# ¿Por qué recibo el error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pilas'"?

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer un juego en "pilas engine" y he visto tutoriales en donde utilizan un editor de codigo llamado "Geany" que al darle f5 ejecuta ese codigo. Pero a mí me aparece un error.

Este seria mi código:

```
import pilas

pilas.iniciar()
nave = pilas.actores.nave()
pilas.ejecutar()
```

Y me aparece el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "programa.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import pilas
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pilas'
> ```

Comment: Hola Desttroyer ¿Has instalado el motor previamente? Mírate https://github.com/hugoruscitti/pilas/wiki/instalacion.

Comment: Hola  FJSevilla mira me he descargado el instalador de pilas de la pagina oficial para windows asi que si puedes decir como hacerlo para windows te lo agradeceria...

Comment: Por lo que veo tu código es para la versión 0.83.0 o anteriores, en la versión actual debería ser  `import pilasengine` y `pilas = pilasengine.iniciar()`. Este es el tutorial oficial basado en la versión actual en Español: http://manual.pilas-engine.com.ar/

Comment: Si amigo te entiendo... pero cuando le doy al f5 en "Geany" se me ejecuta el cmd de windows y me salta este error:                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "juego.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pilasengine
  File "C:\pilas-engine\pilasengine\__init__.py", line 282
    print "%s - Reiniciando" % (time.strftime("%H:%m:%S"))
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)